# Find the algebraic dimension of space of matrices

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

From A. Gathmann's *Algebraic Geometry* (2014):

> **Exercise 2.31.** Let $X$ be the set of all $2 \times 3$ matrices over a field $K$ that have rank at most $1$, considered as a subset of $\mathbb A^6 = \mathrm{Mat}(2\times 3,K)$.
>
> Show that $X$ is an affine variery. Is it irreducible? What is its dimension?

My take on this is the following:

> Call $M_1$, $M_2$ and $M_3$ the three $2 \times 2$ minors of any $2 \times 3$ matrix. Then $$X = V(\det M_1, \det M_2, \det M_3).$$ Trivially, this shows $X$ is an affine variety.
> Moreover, the ideal generated by the three determinants (call it $I$) looks prime (my guess is that $\det M_i$ and $\det M_j$ are coprime when $i \neq j$), thus the above expression is actually an irreducible decomposition of $X$ (which shows, in turn, that $X$ is not reducible).
>
> Finally, I guess $(\det M_i, \det M_j)$ to be the only prime ideals under $I$, so that the (Krull) dimension of the latter is $3$. Hence I guess the dimension of $X$ is $3$ as well.

As you see, there a lot of guesses: are they correct? Do they need more discussion?

Comment: The ideal generated by all three determinants has codimension $2$ and it is prime ( this requires a proof). However, the ideal generated by any two of them is not a prime.

Comment: A heuristic argument that you should expect the dimension to be four is that a $2\times 3$ matrix of rank 1 consists of two linearly dependent rows. I.e., one of the rows is a scalar multiple of the other, which means that the matrix is determined by four parameters, the three numbers in one of the rows and the scalar multiplier. It's often helpful to make these heuristic arguments so that you know what to expect.

Comment: @jgon your argument makes perfect sense to me! I'll try to make it into a proper proof (and to link it to algebraic geometry).

Comment: @Youngsu can you prove your claims? (I want to see how that is done)

Comment: You may find the proof in the paper of Eagon and Hochster, and there are many other sources. For your particular question, you already have an excellent answer by @jgon which I suggest you accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've said, $X$ is the affine variety given by the three determinants.

Let's write this out.

Suppose $$M = \newcommand\bmat{\begin{pmatrix}}\newcommand\emat{\end{pmatrix}}\bmat a & b & c \\ d & e & f \emat$$

Then our space is $$X=\newcommand\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}\Spec k[a,b,c,d,e,f] / (ae-bd, af-cd, bf-ce).$$

Notice that this is the affine cone of the projective variety
$$\Bbb{P}X=\operatorname{Proj} k[a,b,c,d,e,f]/(ae-bd,af-cd,bf-ce),$$
so its dimension will be one more than the dimension of the projective variety.

Localizing at a coordinate, say $a$ for example, we observe $\frac{e}{a}=\frac{bd}{a^2}$, $\frac{f}{a}=\frac{cd}{a^2}$, and then $$\frac{bf}{a^2} = \frac{bcd}{a^3}=\frac{ce}{a^2}.$$
Thus $$D_+(a) = \Spec k\left[\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a},\frac{d}{a}\right] = \Bbb{A}^3.$$

Thus we can cover $\Bbb{P}X$ by $\Bbb{A}^3$s, so $\Bbb{P}X$ is 3 dimensional.

Moreover, the pairwise intersections just correspond to inverting more of the coordinates, so the pairwise intersections of these open sets will be one of $\Bbb{A}^3\setminus V(x)$ or $\Bbb{A}^3\setminus V(xy)$, which are certainly nonempty.

Thus $\Bbb{P}X$ will be irreducible, see Lemma 27.3.3 at [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01OJ).

Since $\Bbb{P}X$ is irreducible and of dimension 3, $X$ is also irreducible and of dimension 4.

**Edit**

Let's see if I can't translate this to a more concrete form, involving only commutative algebra.

We want to show that $P=(ae-bd,af-cd,bf-ce)$ is prime. Noting that the ideal is homogeneous, it suffices to show that if $FG\in P$ with $F$, $G$, homogeneous, then one of $F$ or $G$ is in $P$. Dehomogenize by setting $a=1$. Then we get $F_aG_a \in P_a = (e-bd,f-cd,bf-ce)$ in the ring $k[b,c,d,e,f]$.

Observe that $k[b,c,d,e,f]/(e-bd,f-cd,bf-ce) = k[b,c,d]$, so $P_a$ is prime.
Therefore one of $F_a$ or $G_a$ is in $P_a$. WLOG $F_a\in P_a$, so
$$F_a(b,c,d,e,f) = H(b,c,d,e,f)(e-bd) + J(b,c,d,e,f)(f-cd) + K(b,c,d,e,f)(bf-ce).$$
Rehomogenizing, we obtain
$$a^{\deg F_a}F_a\left(\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a},\frac{d}{a},\frac{e}{a},\frac{f}{a}\right) = a^{\deg F_a}\left(H\left(\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a},\frac{d}{a},\frac{e}{a},\frac{f}{a}\right)\left(\frac{e}{a}-\frac{bd}{a^2}\right) + J\left(\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a},\frac{d}{a},\frac{e}{a},\frac{f}{a}\right)\left(\frac{f}{a}-\frac{cd}{a^2}\right) + K\left(\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a},\frac{d}{a},\frac{e}{a},\frac{f}{a}\right)\left(\frac{bf}{a^2}-\frac{ce}{a^2}\right)\right) \in P$$

Since $$F=a^ka^{\deg F_a}F_a\left(\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a},\frac{d}{a},\frac{e}{a},\frac{f}{a}\right),$$ we see $F\in P$. Thus $P$ is prime.

The property that dehomogenizing and rehomogenizing just kills factors of $a$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/130414/90543).

You'll notice that this argument should prove that the ideals $(ae-bd, af-cd)$ and $(ae-bd)$ are prime as well, the first being prime contrary to Youngsu's comment on the original question, but I'm fairly sure it's correct. Hopefully someone will point it out to me if I'm missing something obvious, but it should be mostly correct, since its roughly a translation of my earlier argument.

Assuming then that we know $P$ is prime, we need to compute the dimension of $k[a,b,c,d,e,f]/P$. Since this is a variety, its dimension is the same as the transcendence degree of the fraction field. Localizing before finding the fraction field gives the same fraction field, so we localize at $a$ first. Thus the dimension of $X$ is the transcendence degree of the fraction field of $k[a,b,c,d,a^{-1}]$ ($e$ and $f$ were killed by localizing at $a$), and the fraction field of this ring is $k(a,b,c,d)$. Thus the transcendence degree is 4, so $\dim X = 4$, as desired.

**Second edit**

There is an error in my proof that $P$ is prime.

Consider the ideal $(ae-bd,af-cd)$. Observe that $b(af-cd) - c(ae-bd) = abf-ace = a(bf-ce)$ lies in this ideal. Neither $a$ nor $bf-ce$ is in the ideal.

The problem is that when we dehomogenize, we get $bf-ce$ is in $P_a$, but its homogenization, also $bf-ce$ is not in $P$.

The error in my proof was that to properly rehomogenize the expression proving $F_a$ was in $P_a$, we may need to multiply by a higher power of $a$ than $\deg F_a$.

Thus we instead must conclude that $a^kF \in P$ for some $k$ rather than $F\in P$. Choose another variable to dehomogenize at, say $b$. Then $a^kF_b \in P_b$, and $P_b$ is prime, but $a\not \in P_b = (ae-d,f-ce)$. Thus $F_b\in P_b$, so $b^jF\in P$ as well. The choice of variable was irrelevant here. Thus for any of the variables $x$, we get $x^{n_x}F \in P$ for some nonnegative integer $n_x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this exercise is at the end of Chapter 2 of Gathmann, where he barely introduced Zariski topology. Hence I'm not yet familiar with all the machinery you're using (since $X = \mathrm{Spec}\ldots$), and actually I doubt it is strictly necessary to solve the exercise. Do you think it could be done more directly?

Comment: @mattecapu Edited

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is much more understandable to me! Great write-up! I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: Just to clarify: in third equality ($F=a^k\ldots$), is $k$ the 'missing degrees' of $a$ when rehomogenizing?

Comment: @mattecapu Yes, but there's a slight error in this proof, which I'm working on fixing.

Comment: I've noticed that error few hours ago, but I didn't have time to post a comment. On the other side, if one can prove that $a$ is a non-zerodivisor on $R/P$ (as you probably have to do if want to save the proof) then it's easily proven that $P$ is prime, since $R/P$ becomes a subring of $R_a/P_a$ which is an integral domain.

Comment: @user26857 Good point, that would also allow me to conclude from showing $a^kF\in P$, since then $F\in P$. I had been trying to modify my proof by being more faithful to the original geometric argument, though I'm unfortunately a bit busy, so I haven't had time to properly think about how to fix this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to prove irreducibility of
$$X=\{A\in\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times m}(K)\mid \mathrm{rank}A\leq r\}.$$

It can be seen as the image of the map $$\phi:\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times r}(K)\times \mathrm{Mat}_{r\times m}(K)\ni (M,N)\mapsto MN\in X.$$

$\phi$ is a polynomial map and hence Zariski continuous.  Further, $$\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times r}(K)\times \mathrm{Mat}_{r\times m}(K)\cong K^{nr+rm}$$ is irreducible, thus so is $X$ (because continuous images of irreducible spaces are irreducible).